# Why are the angle coding of the samples cascaded and only use so few qubits

Tags: quantum-gate

[image]
I want to ask about the angle coding. Is the angle coding that Abbas said really like this? There are two samples and four features. Why does she only use two qubits? Instead of four. And the sample and the sample are separated by a Hadamard gate. Is this design correct?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtsz_ioqbt0&list=PLrfsF3Qlg8YIsu5HKPpFkAEJyR6R_oSHH&index=18

Comment: who is "Abbas"? Please include in the post all relevant links and references

Comment: so sorry, here is the link     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtsz_ioqbt0&list=PLrfsF3Qlg8YIsu5HKPpFkAEJyR6R_oSHH&index=18